Tesseract.js OCR How do I properly set Page Segmentation Mode (PSM, pageseg) to detect a single number in an image
I've been using tesseract to read various numbers (up to 99,999.9) in the format below:

Example of image that OCR failed on: 
It seems to get a proper read about 80% of the time, but I need 95% accuracy.
async function runOCR(url) {
    const worker = await Tesseract.createWorker('eng', 1, {
        tessedit_pageseg_mode: 13,
        config: '--psm 13'
    });

    (async () => {
        await worker.load();
        await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
        await worker.initialize('eng');    
        
        await worker.setParameters({
            tessedit_ocr_engine_mode: Tesseract.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY,
            tessedit_char_whitelist: '0123456789,.',
            preserve_interword_spaces: '0',
            SINGLE_WORD: true,
            tessedit_pageseg_mode: Tesseract.SINGLE_WORD,
        });
        const {
            data: { text },
        } = await worker.recognize(url);
        doSomething(text);
        await worker.terminate();
    })();
}

The main issue is I don't know where to set the Page Segmentation Mode (PSM, pageseg). The examples I'm finding are either out of date or in another language.
Here's a pageseg options list that I found from a C file (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/4.0.0/src/ccstruct/publictypes.h#L163)
  PSM_OSD_ONLY,       ///< Orientation and script detection only.
  PSM_AUTO_OSD,       ///< Automatic page segmentation with orientation and
                      ///< script detection. (OSD)
  PSM_AUTO_ONLY,      ///< Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR.
  PSM_AUTO,           ///< Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD.
  PSM_SINGLE_COLUMN,  ///< Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
  PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK_VERT_TEXT,  ///< Assume a single uniform block of vertically
                               ///< aligned text.
  PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK,   ///< Assume a single uniform block of text. (Default.)
  PSM_SINGLE_LINE,    ///< Treat the image as a single text line.
  PSM_SINGLE_WORD,    ///< Treat the image as a single word.
  PSM_CIRCLE_WORD,    ///< Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
  PSM_SINGLE_CHAR,    ///< Treat the image as a single character.
  PSM_SPARSE_TEXT,    ///< Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
  PSM_SPARSE_TEXT_OSD,  ///< Sparse text with orientation and script det.
  PSM_RAW_LINE,       ///< Treat the image as a single text line, bypassing
                      ///< hacks that are Tesseract-specific.

How can I better detect the numbers in the image OR how do I set the Page Segmentation Mode  / config correctly? (The config changes I've been making don't seem to make a difference in my hit rate)

I'm not too familiar with OCR, but I doubt that any OCR tool can provide actual 100% accuracy. I mean, maybe you get 99.9%, I don't know what's common these days, but I would assume that you should never absolutely rely on these numbers to be correct.

@kca Yeah I understand if I was scraping to insert into a database or something. In my program, I'm clicking, OCRing a number, then doing an action. If the number doesn't OCR properly, I just don't do the action.  I'll then just click again and hope for a clean read on another close enough number. It doesn't have to be perfect, but it is quite annoying when it doesn't work.

https://i.sstatic.net/PabiU.png

@matanh This is an image OCR failed on: https://i.sstatic.net/dtbi2.png
